# Macbook Pro Keyboard Functions Stopped Working on Bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bootcamp, windows

I have a MacBook Pro 15" with Mountain Lion 10.8.

I've had the laptop for about 8 months now and I installed Bootcamp probably around a week after I got it. Everything worked perfectly, which was awesome. Installed the support drivers and everything.

Today I booted into Windows and the keyboard functions have stopped working. For instance the keyboard backlights wont work and the volume buttons do nothing. I tried rebooting a few times into mac and back or back into Windows and nothing works.

Anybody run into this sort of things before? Have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a drivers issue.

Try re-installing the drivers for Windows and reboot. You can download the drivers from [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638). Please double check that your version of Windows is 7 64-bit or 8.